# How to make a shortcode for my WP_Query Loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, custom-field, loop

I'm a noob Wordpress Developer and I just created my first Custom Template Page using Advanced Custom Fields and managed to loop.

```
   <?php 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'art',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );         
        ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> 

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'art' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

But I will like to use it not only inside a template page, but anywhere I want. Therefore I need to create a shortcode.

Example:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

My question would be: How can i put the loop inside my shortcode?

Comment: This may help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213705/combining-shortcode-and-get-template-part

Answer (score 0):

I´m doing this since last year and i´m getting the shortcodes working:

```
   function my_code() {
   ob_start();
   get_template_part('loop_logos');
   return ob_get_clean();   
} 
add_shortcode( 'logos', 'my_code' );
```

where get_template_part loads the file loop_logos.php and logos is the name shortcode [logos].

**HINT**

When I started to do this I used to name all equal to avoid mistakes, Ex:

```
function loop_logos() {
       ob_start();
       get_template_part('loop_logos');
       return ob_get_clean();   
    } 
    add_shortcode( 'loop_logos', 'loop_logos' );
```

So I had to worry about to upload the loop_logos.php on the right folder. and call the shortcode with [loop_logos]

Comment: I used ob_start(); and  return ob_get_clean();  and it worked.